# Using Redux+React to fetch an ID from an API using useParams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux

I'm working with an API that doesn't allow for me to call for a specific id. I've done a work around before using hooks that look something like this

```
import React from 'react'

export const fetchHeroDetail = async (id) => {
    const data = await fetch(`https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats`)
    console.log(data)
    const heroDetails = await data.json()
    console.log(heroDetails)
    console.log(heroDetails.find(heroDetail => heroDetail.id === +id))
    return heroDetails.find(heroDetail => heroDetail.id === +id)

};
```

However I'm using Redux now. My application basically displays the full list of characters and allows you to click on one. When I do, I use the useParams() to take the ID that was clicked on and I was trying to use it to sift through the API. I'm a novice at Redux, so please be gentle. Here is my actions, reducers, the page, and component

heroAction.js

```
import { store } from '../index';
export const GET_HERO = 'GET HERO'
export const GET_HERO_SUCCESS = 'GET_HERO_SUCCESS'
export const GET_HERO_FAILURE = 'GET_HERO_FAILURE'


export const getHero = () => ({
    type: GET_HERO,
})

export const getHeroSuccess = hero => ({
    type: GET_HERO_SUCCESS,
    payload: hero,
})

export const getHeroFailure = () => ({
    type: GET_HERO_FAILURE,
})


export const fetchHero = async() => {
    store.dispatch(getHero())

    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats')
        console.log(response)
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)

        store.dispatch(getHeroSuccess(data))
    } catch (error) {
        store.dispatch(getHeroFailure())
    }
}
```

Hero.js

```
import React from 'react'

export const Hero = ({ hero }) => (
    <h2>
        <h2>{hero.localized_name}</h2>
    </h2>
)
```

HeroPage.js

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

import { fetchHero } from '../actions/heroAction'
import { Hero } from '../components/Hero'
import {useParams} from "react-router";

const HeroPage = () => {
    const data = useSelector(state => state.hero);
    const heroId = useParams()
    useEffect(() => {
        (fetchHero(heroId))
    }, [heroId])

    const renderHero = () => {
        if (data.loading) return <p>Loading posts...</p>
        if (data.hasErrors) return <p>Unable to display posts.</p>
        return data.hero.find(hero => <Hero key={hero.id} hero={hero} />)
    }

    return (
        <section>
            <h1>Hero</h1>
            {renderHero()}
        </section>
    )
}


export default HeroPage
```

heroReducer.js

```
import * as actions from '../actions/heroAction'

export const initialState = {
    hero: [],
    loading: false,
    hasErrors: false,
}

export default function heroReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actions.GET_HERO:
            return { ...state, loading: true }
        case actions.GET_HERO_SUCCESS:
            return { hero: action.payload, loading: false, hasErrors: false }
        case actions.GET_HERO_FAILURE:
            return { ...state, loading: false, hasErrors: true }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: your code looks neat overall. `fetchHero` doesnt accept params at first glance, though you call it with `heroId`. are you using any redux async middleware here? you need to pick one for running async calls with redux.

Comment: @buzatto I was just reading about this. I was thinking redux-thunk but I have no clue how I should implement it. when I run this as is. It just gives me that Objects are not valid as React Children, I'm assuming it means when I try to ```return data.hero.find(hero => <Hero key={hero.id} hero={hero} />)``` but then again i'm not sure

Comment: for redux-thunk, your action must return another function that takes dispatch as param like: `const myAsyncAction = (myQuery) => (dispatch) => { return fetch(myQuery).then(res => dispatch(myAction(res))) }`. redux-thunk will check if it's a function and if it's , delays dispatch trigger. you may check the [docs example](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#composition)

Comment: @buzatto it's just weird that with my other function fetchHeroes, where it just grabs all of the heroes' avaiable it doesn't shoot me a error, only when I search for something.

Answer (score 0):

with redux-thunk your async code will look something like:

```
export const fetchHero = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch(getHero())

  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats')
    console.log(response)
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)

    dispatch(getHeroSuccess(data))
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(getHeroFailure())
  }
}
```

Comment: So your example works when I copy in it and I don't receive an error and I finally reach just the regular Hero component. However, when I get there, nothing is being shown. I'm assuming I need to add a query into the fetchHero

Comment: you could break in two. you could call fetch heroStats right away once you load app. after that, once client picks up one hero you do a filter action, so client wont need to wait for the async action to resolve.

Comment: would adding a query be the correct way with your example? It's currently working I just don't have anything showing up on the page, so I assume that my fetch function isn't returning anything based on the parameters that I have

Comment: just another approach. since you cant fetch for a specific heroId at the api, (you always get all) imo it's better to fetch right away all and populate your redux store. then on some client action you take your redux store and do the filter. you can use the same approach you used before, but you are making unnecessary requests since you get always the same heroes result. I suggest you use [redux devTools extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension). it's pretty handy to check your state change, and if everything is correct.